# WPF Set DataGrid-ItemSource from List does not generating column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here i set ItemSource,

```
 customApplicationHome.dataGridViewCustomApplication.ItemsSource = applicationList;
```

then autogenerating column method is not firing

```
 private void dataGridViewCustomApplication_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Column.Header = Utils.Util.SplitCamelCase(e.Column.Header.ToString());
    }
```

and xaml for binding the above method is

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridViewCustomApplication" 
    AlternationCount="2"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="0"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    ColumnWidth="*"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="0,20,0,85"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Binding,AncestorLevel=1}}"
    Height="320"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    EnableRowVirtualization="False"
    AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGridViewCustomApplication_AutoGeneratingColumn" 
    Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting"
    LayoutUpdated="dataGrid_LayoutUpdated" 
    CopyingRowClipboardContent="DataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent" />
```

Also note that, the list i am using as ItemSource is working fine in other data grid.

Comment: Is there anything visible inside the debug window? Like mentioning of a missing method on a particular view?

Comment: no, there is no error & missing method :)

Comment: Then, is the property `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `"True"`? It is a bit hard to check since you are only showing the one property :)

Comment: no, i have updated the code. pls check

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) both seem required

Comment: sorry, could not get your comment, explanation pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135493/discussion-between-ghost-developer-and-icepickle).

Comment: It's just like what I said, in order to use the method, you also need the `AutoGenerateColumns` property, and not only the `AutoGeneratingColumn`. If the first one is set to true, the second one should be called when the data gets bound and the columns are generated. The link I added to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) page shows an example of how to implement it, so I am not sure what you might be missing still

Comment: The AutoGenerateColumns property of the DataGrid is set to True by default. But what is "customApplicationHome"? Make sure that this is a reference to the view where the DataGrid that you see on the screen and is defined.